# Z3 : Why does MBQI instantiate this quantifier but e-matching does not?

Tags: z3, smt

In the following code, `z3` appears not to instantiate the quantifier `nil-cons`:

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)
(set-option :smt.ematching true)
(set-option :smt.qi.profile true)
(declare-sort Lis 0)
(declare-sort Elem 0)
(declare-const nil Lis)
(declare-fun cons (Elem Lis) Lis)
(assert
  (forall
    ((x Elem) (xs Lis))
    (! (not
      (=
        nil
        (cons x xs)
      )
    )
      :pattern ((cons x xs))
      :qid nil-cons
      )
  )
)
(declare-const global_x Elem)
(declare-const global_xs Lis)
(assert
    (=
      nil
      (cons global_x global_xs)
    )
)
(check-sat)
```

However, with mbqi enabled the quantifier appears to be instantiated.

The result is that with ematching, `z3` returns `unknown` while using mbqi it returns `unsat` (corresponding to the contradiction of the `nil-cons` axiom and the final unquantified assertion).

Does anyone have any idea why the `nil-cons` axiom is not be instantiated via ematching? It seems to me like the pattern should match.

Comment: If you change `(set-option :auto-config false)` to `true`, you'll see that it instantiates just fine. It isn't clear to me though why that makes a difference. There's very little documentation on what exactly `auto-config` does.

Comment: Right - although it isn't clear to me whether auto_config can override the manually-set options, here. Since mbqi is on by default, it could just be that auto_config finds the proof by means other than e-matching.

Comment: It does indeed seem like auto_config overrides the mbqi settings. The [Axiom Profiler](https://github.com/viperproject/axiom-profiler) indicates that the quantifier was instantiated via mbqi